# Puppet and Agent configuration

Tags: puppet

I m actually trying to create an Agent from Puppet and I m facing a problem.

In fact, I have the standard generated puppet.conf file in my agent that globally look like this :

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

Actually, I m trying to find where I should set my master information inside of the agent ? How can my agent connect to the master in this file ?

I didn't find anything great concerning this in the documentation...

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an agent block. Something similar to the following:

You can run `puppet agent --genconfig` to know about other attributes.

```
[agent]
# The server to which puppet agent should connect 
server = mypuppet.server.org

# The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
# associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
# the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
# option.
# The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

# Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
# extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
# The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

# How often puppet agent applies the client configuration; in seconds.
# Note that a runinterval of 0 means "run continuously" rather than
# "never run." If you want puppet agent to never run, you should start
# it with the `--no-client` option.
# The default value is '1800'.
runinterval = 86400
```

Answer (score 1):

My `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` had this in it:

```
[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

and I simply added this one line after `localconfig`

```
server = host.fq.dn.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no require to change in `puppet.conf` for puppet master.

You need add `puppet` in your DNS, that you can run `nslookup puppet` to get its IP address

If you don't have dns servers, then you should add it in each puppet agent's local `/etc/hosts`, for example

```
10.0.0.4 puppet puppet.example.com
```

After that, when you run `puppet agent -t`, the agent will automatically communicate with the server `puppet`.

Note: make sure the firewalls are opened between puppet agent and master server.